# mysql LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with default timestamp column value

Tags: mysql, jdbc, load-data-infile

I've a table which has a column defined like this:

```
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| created_at  | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
```

and I insert data using this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<path_to_the_file>' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' (<some_columns>,created_at,<more_columns>)
```

from a file where each line is like this:

**822202|NETGEAR|||||1448ce8f-efc5-7b07-6982-1ff991bf967e||||||||1|||**

Note: **created_at** is the 5th column, so the file has no value for it, therefore I expect CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

instead, this is what I see:

```
mysql> select distinct created_at from my_table;
+---------------------+
| created_at          |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

the code running the command is, supposedly, using a standard JDBC, it's a jdbc.clj Clojure library.

Note 2: if I run INSERT INTO ... query manually, it (obviously) works as expected.

Anyone can tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried execute the query from workbench, query browser, phpmyadmin, or console without use JDBC?

Comment: Good question; directly from mysql CLI console it's failing like this: ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.25, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper // mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 5.6.25 for osx10.10 on x86_64 (Homebrew) ---- both are rather new

Comment: Check: `TIMESTAMP columns are set to the current date and time only if there is a NULL value for the column (that is, \N) and the column is not declared to permit NULL values, or if the TIMESTAMP column's default value is the current timestamp and it is omitted from the field list when a field list is specified.` - [13.2.6 LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html).

Comment: I think you've got something there, @wchiquito. Now I'll need to figure out what's the behavior of "||" (empty string between two delimiters) vs the 'NULL, that is \N', as per the text..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;

CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `column0` VARCHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `column1` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `column2` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `column3` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `column5` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

File:

`/path/to/test_file.txt`

```
822202|NETGEAR||||1
822203|NETGEAR1|||2000-01-01 00:00:00|2
822204|NETGEAR2|||NULL|3
822205|NETGEAR3|||\N|4
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/test_file.txt'
       INTO TABLE `test_table`
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
       (`column0`, `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, @`created_at`, `column5`)
       SET `created_at` = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(@`created_at`)) = 0
                          OR
                          TRIM(@`created_at`) = 'NULL', NULL, @`created_at`);
```